# Ajax post to full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, gcal

I am working on adding events to the full calendar which is intern connected to google calendar via ajax post, but the result isn't successful, though i do not get any errors, but the get call and the delete is successful(here i mean to say that the delete, deletes an event from my GCAL and the Get gets all events from my Gcal)
this  is my HTML and JS file

Could anyone please guide here
Thanks in advance

```js
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        //CalendarGoogle.init();

        $('#add_event_submit').click(function(){
            var title = $('#title').val();
            var start = $('#start').val();
            var end = $('#end').val();
            alert(title+" "+start);


            function send() {
                var data = {
                    summary: $("#title").val(),
                    start:$("#start").val(),
                    end:$("#end").val()
                }

                $('#target').html('sending..');

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/subhanu.com_7ejfdkhes1vhgommacqo86l85k@group.calendar.google.com/events?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                       console.log(data);
                    },
                    data: events
                });
            }
            });

        });
```

```html
<form role="form" name="add_event_form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Event Name: </label>
        <input class="form-control" name="title" id="title"placeholder="Customer">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Start: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="start" id="start" placeholder="">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>End: </label>
        <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="end" id="end" placeholder="">
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="add_event_submit">
            <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
            Add Event</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to fix a few things:

Firstly : You don't need a function inside the event, The function is only getting registered and not getting called.

```
function send() {
```

Secondly: `data: events` here events is not declared

the source code after making the change is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    //CalendarGoogle.init();

    $('#add_event_submit').click(function(){
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var start = $('#start').val();
        var end = $('#end').val();
        console.log(title+" "+start);

        var data = {
                summary: $("#title").val(),
                start:$("#start").val(),
                end:$("#end").val()
            }
          console.log(data);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/subhanu.com_7ejfdkhes1vhgommacqo86l85k@group.calendar.google.com/events?access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                   console.log("success");
                   console.log(data);
                },
                data: data
            }).always(function()
                   {
              console.log("done");
            });

        });

    });
```

Codepen for reference:
https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/BYdMJE

Comment: thanks, but the event is yet not getting posted to the gcal, what could be the possible issue ?

Comment: Check the network tab, the request goes, and there is an error in the response.

Comment: Error:
code:401
errors:[{domain: "global", reason: "required", message: "Login Required", locationType: "header",…}]
message:"Login Required"

Comment: A 401 means you haven't provided the correct authentication to the google API. I would suggest using their provided JS library - https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/ to interact with the API

Comment: @Yasir may be that's cos of the credentials, i dint get you right.

Comment: @Snehitha the api call is now working, try using the right data

Comment: @Yasir could you please tell me the "format" of the right data, sorry yet not resolved with it

Comment: @Snehitha: please go through the documentation: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/